# How to handle multiple Downloads in Selenium IDE withouth a forced stop of the process?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to download multiple files with Selenium IDE.
The page I am working on is behind login. 
Those are my steps:
1. Login
2. Navigate to the page
3. Search for Data
4. Download PDF ---
5. Download xlsx
6. Continue with other tests

Unfortunately Selenium stops after clicking on the PDF-icon (4.). It downloads the PDF automatically (chrome-settings) and then stops the whole process. Why is it stoping and how can I handle that problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for us.
Note that as mentioned in the source comments below that download does not work

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", [
    "download.default_directory": downloadDir.absolutePath,
    "download.prompt_for_download": false,
    "download.directory_upgrade": true,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": true
])
// Headless mode does not work, because currently Chrome does not allow downloads in headless mode
// See
// https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5159
// https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481
// options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-browser-side-navigation", "--no-sandbox")

def driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
```